# RabbitMQ Topic format - sub-topic under main topic

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit

When I am trying to push to topic in this format **/topic/pushing/{organizationId}** I am getting an error

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/pushing/" + obj.getCustomerid(), obj);
```

The error:

> 15:06:48.901 [reactor-tcp-io-1] ERROR
>   o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Received ERROR
>   {message=[Invalid destination], content-type=[text/plain],
>   version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[53]} session=*system*
>   text/plain **payload='/pushing/2963_ent' is not a valid topic
>   destination**

However when I change it to this format **/topic/pushing.{organizationId}**, replacing the slash with dot, it's working fine:

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/pushing." + obj.getCustomerid(), obj);
```

Any idea how I can keep the slash / and have sub-topics under the main topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AMQP 0.9.1 specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf) has this to say about topic exchanges:

> The topic exchange type works as follows:
>   1. A message queue binds to the exchange using a routing pattern, P.
>   2. A publisher sends the exchange a message with the routing key R.
>   3. The message is passed to the message queue if R matches P. The routing key used for a topic exchange MUST consist of zero or more
>   words delimited by dots. Each word may contain the letters A-Z and a-z
>   and digits 0-9.
>
> The routing pattern follows the same rules as the routing key with the
>   addition that * matches a single word, and # matches zero or more
>   words. Thus the routing pattern *.stock.# matches the routing keys
>   usd.stock and eur.stock.db but not stock.nasdaq.

So "/" are not authorized in the routing key, and delimiter used is a dot.